# Do we need the comma after 'following' here? "The following, concise descriptions of..."

Tags: adjectives, punctuation, commas

My intuition is telling me that there should be no comma after 'following' in the sentence "The following, concise descriptions of...", however, I am not sure. I have never really considered 'following' as a 'true' adjective.

Can anyone tell me whether this is grammatically correct?

Comment: We could judge better with the whole sentence. You might want an appositive pair of commas here: The following, concise descriptions of each issue rather than the full details, are ready for your review.

Answer (score 0):

> A comma should be placed between two adjectives (of equal rank) that describe the same noun. Adjectives “of equal rank” are adjectives that can exchange locations in the sentence with one another such that the sentence will still make sense. **Adjectives which do not have equal rank do not require a comma.**

An example of adjectives of different rank:

> *Several happy* people danced in the streets upon hearing the news.

I would argue that 'following' and 'concise' are of different rank here, even though switching their order still mostly makes sense.

Comment: "even though switching their order still mostly makes sense" - does it though?

"The concise, following descriptions of..." sounds a bit nonsensical to me

Comment: I think you could add a comma or not add a coma, but that would slightly change the meaning of the sentence. Imagine if after that sentence, follow several descriptions, some of which are concise and some of which are not.

Comment: Could you please add the source of the quotation?